How can I write to a output tab on Visual Studio 2022 extension startup?
I am making an extension for Visual Studio 2022. When the extension starts up (like when the user opens Visual Studio) I want to start writing some logging information to the Output in a custom "Select Output From" tab.
I have the following class I'm using for writing to the output.
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using System;

namespace MyExtension;

public class OutputWindow
{
    private Guid OutputWindowGuid = new("1a9b495d-6b1a-4076-b244-98d0a5663053");
    private readonly IVsOutputWindowPane outputPane;

    public OutputWindow()
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        if (ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow))
                is IVsOutputWindow obj)
        {
            obj.CreatePane(ref OutputWindowGuid, "MyTestPanel", 1, 0);
            obj.GetPane(ref OutputWindowGuid, out outputPane);
        }
    }

    internal void WriteLine(in string v)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        outputPane.OutputStringThreadSafe(v + "\n");
    }
}

And then I use it like this
protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
{
    await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);
    await LogAsync("TEST LOG");
}

internal async Task LogAsync(string v)
{
    await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
    OutputWindow.WriteLine(v);
}

However this doesnt seem to write anything on startup. How can I get it to write? For that matter, I cant seem to get any code to execute on startup. I thought anything in the InitializeAsync would be run on start?

what does your package class inherit? Its not shown here

@D3vtr0n do you mean what is before the InitializeAsync? I have this there.
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
[Guid(MyExtension.PackageGuidString)]
public sealed class MyExtension: AsyncPackage

Hi @QuestionAsker, i would suggest you to ask for help and figure out  "how  Codeium extension works " at Codeium extension


I thought anything in the InitializeAsync would be run on start?

No, InitializeAsync doesn't run on start. Because when everybody runs on start, people wonder why their Visual Studio takes forever to launch!
Your package will be loaded when something else triggers the package to load. This is either because something the package offers (like a tool window) is used, or you've used the PackageAutoLoad to specify when the package should load. See this documentation for details.

This raises the question about how this Codeium extension works. I am using this as a reference.
Specifically, you'll notice in this file the InitializeAsync is similar to what I have and in this file there is the OutputWindow. The Output is written the moment I open my ide. But the ProvideAutoLoad is commented out at the top of CodeiumVSPackage.cs.

@QuestionAsker Codeium implements a tool window and (probably) a MEF component that additionally force the package to load.

Ok so I tried adding the PackageAutoLoad as it is on the linked page, and couldn't get that to work.
I dont want to add a output window to my extension, nor a command in the tool bar. Is it possible to have it load without any user input in that regard? Is there an example of the MEF method you might be able to link me? Apologies, this is my first time doing anything with Visual Studio and it isn't too intuitive to me.
